# How to proxy fulfillment URL for google actions

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am developing a voice-bot using Dialogflow and Google Assistant.

My webhook and API are in a private network and I can access my webhook through proxy only, which is provided by the client. I have routed Google assistant using the gactions CLI such that every request to Google Assistant will hit the proxy first and it will reach my fulfillment URL.

My question is: is there anything to be done from the client side for redirecting the Google assistant request to my webhook from the proxy? Or any other workaround for this? Can I specify my proxy and fulfillment URL in actions.json?

Answer (score 0):

The fulfillment URL is the one which Google Assistant (GA) will hit to communicate with your webhook. For development, you can run local webhook server and expose it to internet using [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/).
You will run you local server, then run the ngrok and provide your server port. It will generate an internet facing URL which you can use as fulfillment URL for GA.

When you are done with developement, it would be better to use cloud as response time is critical in GA apps. If running locally, your proxy should allow GA to communicate with your webhook. You may require to contact your local network team to white list requests coming from GA servers to your webhook. You can see GA logs for the communication errors that may arise in the process.